# Mapping checkbox id's to return related properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping

I have a table with checkboxes, each box has an id associated with it. When that checkbox is selected it looks up the id and returns other properties related to that id. This then updates the state.

All fine except when I click on another checkbox! The original object in my array becomes undefined but the 2nd object returns correct. On the 3rd click I cant do anything as it breaks at this point.

https://codesandbox.io/s/18xorzw46q

Here is my click handler:

```
  handleCheckboxClick = (event, id, name) => {
    event.stopPropagation();

    const { selected, selectedDialog } = this.state;
    const selectedIndex = selected.indexOf(id);
    let newSelected = [];

    if (selectedIndex === -1) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected, { id, name });
    } else if (selectedIndex === 0) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(1));
    } else if (selectedIndex === selected.length - 1) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(0, -1));
    } else if (selectedIndex > 0) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(
        selected.slice(0, selectedIndex),
        selected.slice(selectedIndex + 1)
      );
    }

    console.log("selectedDialog", newSelected);
    this.setState({
      selected: newSelected.map(n => n.playerId),
      selectedDialog: newSelected.map(({ id, name }) => ({ id, name }))
    });

  };
```

I've got a console log in there to demo the point to which `newSelected` gets returned with the selected checkbox.

```
0: {id: "14", name: "bob"}
```

then on 2nd selection of another checkbox:

```
0: undefined
1: {id: "15", name: "tyler"}
```

Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/18xorzw46q

Comment: What should `selected` and `newSelected` be? A list of ids, or a list of {id, name}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code logic is too entangled, so it hid the error from you.

You are using `newSelected` and `this.state.selected` as both an array of `id` and an array of `{id, name}` (not to mention the unknown `n.playerId`). I'm not sure which format you actually want, but just try to simplify your code:

```
handleCheckboxClick = (event, id, name) => {
    event.stopPropagation();

    const { selected, selectedDialog } = this.state;
    const isSelected = selected.includes(id);
    const newSelected = isSelected
      ? selected.filter(item => item !== id)
      : [...selected, id];
    const newSelectedDialog = isSelected
      ? selectedDialog.filter(item => item.id !== id)
      : [...selectedDialog, { id, name }];

    console.log("selectedDialog", newSelected);
    this.setState({
      selected: newSelected,
      selectedDialog: newSelectedDialog
    });
  };
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/0q5ox9ll1w

Comment: playerId is just id, change from to that for simplicity

Comment: Ooh I think I get what you're planning to do. Check my updated answer.

Comment: selectedDialog returns 0:undefined - I will need to put newSelected.map(({ id, name }) => ({ id, name })) but does not return

Comment: Will I need to adjust handle to remove isSelected when deselecting so record does not appear in array? Thanks @AVAVT